# `Update from SubQuery` not work in Go gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I would like to use below mysql update to update data.

```sql
update goods t1, user t2 
set t1.user_id = t2.user_id where t1.phone ? and t2.phone = ?
```

I am tring to use below gorm query `Update from SubQuery` to solve it,

`models.DB.Model(&models.User{}).Select("user_id").Where("goods.phone = ? and users.phone = ?", row[3], row[3]))`

but subquery not work, log.Println `UPDATE good SET user_id = 0`, if I declare a user and good model as `users` and `goods` above the above code,

```
var users models.User
var goods models.Good
```

I will get error of `users and goods declared but not used`, is there anyone who knows how to solve it? Thanks so much for any help.